# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in multi-variable logistics regression

Tags: python, scipy

I'm making the Logistics regression with 2 value a and b associate with binary c value (0 and 1). My script for construction of the Logistics regression is below (constructed based on references from https://realpython.com/logistic-regression-python/#logistic-regression-python-packages)

```
def log_reg(c,a,b):
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

    x_list = [[a[x],b[x]] for x in range(len(a))]
    x = np.array(x_list).reshape(-1,2)
    y = np.array(c)
    

    model = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state = 0)
    model.fit(x,y)

    b0 = model.intercept_[0]
    b = model.coef_[0]
    b1 = b[0]
    b2 = b[1]
    print('Logistic Regression accurate is:',model.score(x,y))
    del np, LogisticRegression
    return b0,b1,b2
```

Before the script run, variables are constructed as below:

```
a = a_1 + a_0
b = b_1 + b_0
c = [1]*len(a_1) + [0]*len(a_0)
```

But when I run, the terminal return this:

```
/dir/to/file/test.py:54: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  x = np.array(x_list).reshape(-1,1)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 13, in test
    b0, b1, b2 = log_reg(g, crX, crY)
  File "/dir/to/file/test.py", line 61, in log_reg
    model.fit(x,y)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py", line 1344, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 433, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 814, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 616, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/user/Documents/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

EDIT: I solved the problem, thanks to hpauji I figured out that I misscode the making of all x values

Comment: It's having problems turning `x` into an array (probably numeric).  What is `x.shape` and `x.dtype`.  May also need the same for `y`

Comment: @hpaulj you are right, I misscode on the making of x value before and instead of concatenate 2 groups together its concatenate a group including multiple subgroups so the array failed. I just fix it and problem solved. Thank you very much